# How to enable GCP service "artifactregistry.googleapis.com" with Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to create a GCP project with terraform.

I have a GCP service enable script for Terraform:

```
resource "google_project_service" "gcp_service_apis" {
  for_each = toset(var.gcp_service_list)

  project = var.project
  service = each.key

  disable_on_destroy = false # safety mechanism that should according to docs prevent the api from being disabled if accidentally someone destroys the resource
}
```

I have a list of GCP services in .tfvars file:

- ```
  "run.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "storage.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "pubsub.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "secretmanager.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "servicenetworking.googleapis.com",
  ```
- ```
  "artifactregistry.googleapis.com",
  ```

when Github Actions runs the workflow, I have an error at running Terraform Plan step. You can find the command that I am using:

`terraform plan -no-color -var-file="${{ env.TF_VARS }}"`

Here is the error message:

```
Terraform planned the following actions, but then encountered a problem:

  # google_project_service.gcp_service_apis["artifactregistry.googleapis.com"] will be created
  + resource "google_project_service" "gcp_service_apis" {
      + disable_on_destroy = false
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + project            = "my-project"
      + service            = "artifactregistry.googleapis.com"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Error: Error when reading or editing ArtifactRegistryRepository "projects/my-project/locations/my-location/repositories/my-repo": googleapi: Error 403: Artifact Registry API has not been used in project "my-project" before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-project then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
      {
        "description": "Google developers console API activation",
        "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/artifactregistry.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-project"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
    "domain": "googleapis.com",
    "metadata": {
      "consumer": "projects/my-project",
      "service": "artifactregistry.googleapis.com"
    },
    "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
  }
]
```

Is there any way to enable a GCP service in Terraform. I do not have direct authentication to enable the services. Also, in documentation, it says, using only "resource google_project_service" should enable the resource. However, it is not.

Thank you for your help in advance!

I have tried different kind of approaches but none of them works. I got stuck in artifactregistry step.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but for anyone else https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-project-factory takes `activate_apis` as a parameter and "artifactregistry.googleapis.com" works there.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a separate resource [ArtifactRegistryRepository](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/artifact_registry_repository) "projects/my-project/locations/my-location/repositories/my-repo".

If you're going to declare the repo in the same plan as the API is enabled, then you need a [`depends_on`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) tag for the `resource google_artifact_registry_repository`.

I usually just deploy twice, once to enable the API then later to use the API.